# Is there an alternative to a self-piercing saddle valve for a humidifier?

Tags: plumbing, water, humidity, saddle-valve

I bought and installed a whole home humidifier.  The humidifier is located in my attic connected to the air exchanger.  The Self-Piercing Saddle Valve is located there as well to draw water to the flow through screen.  Since the valve is at the highest water point, I seem to get suction around the rubber gasket and air gets into the pipe and I have to flush that zone every day or 2.  Is there an alternative to the saddle valve?

Comment: Does having a humidifier mean you're likely to get mold? Or are you doing something else to mitigate that?

Comment: the main living floor is very dry during the winter and we have a room humidifier, but wanted something a bit more substantial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a self piercing saddle valve on my whole house humidifier when I bought the house.  It had developed mineral deposits in the piercing hole and no longer worked.  I ended up taking it off, cutting the pipe and sweating in a regular valve.  Self-piercing valves are notorious for clogging up and also for eventually leaking.  Since it is in you attic, any leak would drip down onto you ceiling and cause water damage.  I would consider replacing it with a regular valve.

Comment: Agreed.  The self-piercing valve that the previous owners installed in my home for the refrigerator ice maker sprung a leak about 2 years ago.  Luckily, it was in the basement, and it happened while I had framing up, but before I had drywall up for my finishing job.  I had a plumber come in and replace it, as well as the other self-piercing time bomb that they had installed for the humidifier.

Comment: I installed a T to the humidifier, so far so good.  Thanks for the Advice!